# PhpStorm high CPU usage when typing

Tags: macos, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I started to notice something very annoying with PhpStorm lately. Whenever I type code, the CPU usage goes through the roof, like 300% CPU usage. It seems like something goes wrong with one of the processes that starts when I type, like their auto-complete engine.

I had this issue once before and it turned out to be caused by Dropbox. I was editing some code stored in Dropbox and since PhpStorm saves on every keystroke, Dropbox got triggered and started compressing/encrypting my data. However, this time I don't have any Cloud service running and if I check Activity Monitor, it's the PhpStorm process that has the high CPU usage.

Does anyone have any idea what this could be? I'm not running any weird plugins, just stock + the .ignore plugin. My projects all have Git version control configured in PhpStorm.

Already tried reinstalling PhpStorm, unfortunately, this didn't work.

Environment info:

```
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)
2.3 GHz Intel Core i7
16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
macOS Siera 10.12.5
PhpStorm 2017.2.3 build #PS-172.4155.25
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
```

Comment: **1)** With this kind of issue you should be contacting PhpStorm support directly -- they know better their product and what might be affecting performance (after you provide some info on their request) and what can be checked/improved here. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: **2)** *"...and since PhpStorm saves on every keystroke..."* That's NOT true -- it does not do that by default. It may only happen like that if you are in Live Edit session .. or have setup a File Watcher and configured it to be executed immediately (which is your own choice/user error).

Comment: @LazyOne Hi, I submitted the question to their support as well. Thought I'd post it here as there are quite a lot of people who use Jetbrains products here and wondered if there would be someone who experienced the same problem. Thanks for the edit btw.

Comment: **3)** *"I'm not running any weird plugins, just stock + the .ignore plugin."* That plugin might be an issue -- it's causing different indexing issues depending on project structure and your actions .. and previous point (#2 above) might be triggering it (just a guess though .. but with some good probability). It may also depend on what the file content is (how many injection fragments inside; is it a single language (e.g. pure PHP) or multiple languages (mix of PHP and HTML/JS)), how big the file is (if file is bigger that 8K lines or so then IDE gets slower and slower)

Comment: @LazyOne Ah, I thought it was at every keystoke but I guess it does it when you stop typing then? I didn't change any settings but I never hit command+S to save. 

It's not the .ignore plugin. I just tried uninstalling it but the problem persists. Also, used that plugin for years without issues.

Comment: @RoemerBakker Hi there, I'm encountering the same issue, Have you found a solution about that?

Comment: @huachengzan I'd contact Jetbrains, that's what I did. They helped me really well and had some good suggestions. However, at some point, the issue went away for me the same way it came.

Comment: @huachengzan I'd contact Jetbrains, that's what I did. They helped me really well and had some good suggestions. However, at some point, the issue went away for me the same way it came.

Comment: @RoemerBakker Could you please share some suggestions with me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @huachengzan I can forward you the chain if you provide your email

Comment: I have the same problem!

Comment: I´m having the same issue. How to solve it? I´m having to give up phpStorm and instead use VsCode because of this...